# Tkinter Grid Method Query. No Need to Put in Return From a Function

Tags: python, tkinter

When I was designing my Ui by Tkinter tool, I was confused by some codes from others. From the code below, it has a function my_coinportfolio to trigger the loop, which is to create Label. However, this function doesn't return anything. My question is why I can still see result printed on screen?

Please shed some lights to me.

```
api_response = [
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "9451.36954216", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "13472387097.5", 
        "market_cap_usd": "168674102818", 
        "available_supply": "17846525.0", 
        "total_supply": "17846525.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.13", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-2.0", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-7.08", 
        "last_updated": "1564463368"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "207.595410461", 
        "price_btc": "0.02198341", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "5469338196.61", 
        "market_cap_usd": "22235200091.0", 
        "available_supply": "107108341.0", 
        "total_supply": "107108341.0", 
        "max_supply": None, 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.01", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-2.52", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-3.26", 
        "last_updated": "1564463364"
    }]

pycryptp = Tk()
pycryptp.title("Digital Currency Application")


## Define Heading
name = Label(pycryptp, text = 'Coin Symbol')
name.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

price = Label(pycryptp, text = 'Price')
price.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

holding_amount = Label(pycryptp, text = 'Holding Amount')
holding_amount.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

proftloss = Label(pycryptp, text = 'Profit & Loss')
proftloss.grid(row = 0, column = 3)


## Define Function for app
def my_coinportfolio():
    coin_buyinfo = [
              {
               "symbol": "BTC",
               "number_of_coins": 2,
               "buy_price": 3200
              },
              {
               "symbol": "ETH",
               "number_of_coins": 1.43,
               "buy_price": 290
              },
              {
               "symbol": "BCH",
               "number_of_coins": 0.78,
               "buy_price": 530
              }
        ]
    coin_row = 1
    pl_list = []
    api_response_json = api_response
    for coin in coin_buyinfo:
         for i in range(3):
                symbol = api_response_json[i]['symbol']
                if symbol == coin['symbol']:
                      name = api_response_json[i]['name']
                      price = api_response_json[i]['price_usd']
                      pl = (float(price) - coin['buy_price'])*coin['number_of_coins']
                      pl_list.append(pl)
                      numholding = coin['number_of_coins']
                      ss = Label(pycryptp, text = symbol)
                      ss.grid(row = coin_row, column = 0)

                      dd = Label(pycryptp, text = str(price))
                      dd.grid(row = coin_row, column = 1)

                      vv = Label(pycryptp, text = str(numholding))
                      vv.grid(row = coin_row, column = 2)

                      proftloss = Label(pycryptp, text = str(pl))
                      proftloss.grid(row = coin_row, column = 3)
         coin_row = coin_row +1


## Call Function to initiate grid
my_coinportfolio()

pycryptp.mainloop()
```

Comment: what printed result do you see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all functions must return something. In the end, a function is merely a container for a code to be repeated in a clean way. That is, instead of copying it everywhere.

Of course, a lot of functions return values to be used by calling them. But some functions' purpose is simply to print, or activate stuff, as in your example. Here, the function creates different labels according to some parameters and is simply used to pack the code in a readable fashion. There is no value needed to be returned!

With that said, functions actually do **always** return. When a function does not explicitly return (by using `return`), it will automatically return `None`.

A few simple examples to catch the idea:

```py
def my_func():
    print("Hello")
```

And now we can do:

```
>>> x = my_func()
Hello
>>> print(x)
None
```

As you can see, by calling the function our print statement was executed, and the returned value inside `x` is `None`.